# How to stream from mac to a DLNA Renderer?

Tags: macos, audio, software-recommendation, streaming

I've been wondering if theres an App for letting DLNA clients see my Mac as a DLNA server.

Pointing that the target device does not browse DLNA servers, it just receives a targeted streaming.

In case anyone is wondering, it's a UC46 Mini Projector

It also works with Miracast, if by some miracle someone know how to use it on mac...

What software or scripts can enable this?

Answer (score 2):

There are two free options you can try:

- [ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide)
- [VLC](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo)

VLC offers a more friendly GUI interface though (IMO) it's much more limited.  ffmpeg is much more powerful, but it requires you to be command line savvy.

Personally, I prefer ffmpg.  They have a [tutorial](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide#Pointtopointstreaming) on how to stream point-to-point, which is what you are looking to do

> #### Point to point streaming
>
> If you want to stream "from one computer to another", you could start
>   up a server on one, and then stream from FFmpeg to that server, then
>   have the client connect to that server (server could either be on
>   client or server side computers). Or you could do a point to point
>   type stream, like:
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -i INPUT -acodec libmp3lame -ar 11025 --f rtp rtp://host:port
> ```
>
> where host is the receiving IP. Then receive the stream using VLC or
>   ffmpeg from that port (since rtp uses UDP, the receiver can start up
>   any time).
>
> or
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -i INPUT -f mpegts udp://host:port
> ```

Comment: neither of then support subtitles, i need some app that do what iStream does, but with subtitle, anyone?

Comment: Why is that requirement ***NOT*** in your original question????